# Запятая "в то время(,) как"

Tags: пунктуация

Как разобраться, в каких случаях надо ставить запятую, а когда - нет. 
В частности, в этом случае она нужна? 
"В то время как остальные жили в мире и согласии".

Answer (score 4):

> ***В то время как*** остальные жили в мире и согласии.

Запятая не нужна. ***[В то вре́мя как](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/144710/%D0%92)*** -- союз, присоединяющий придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения.

Хотя для более точного решения этого вопроса желательно было бы иметь контекст.

> [**в то время(,) как**](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/112)
>
> ```
> **союз**
> ```
>
> Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза ***«в то время как»***, >выделяются знаками препинания (обычно запятыми). При этом
>   первый знак препинания может ставиться либо перед составным союзом,
>   либо между его частями (перед словом «как»). О факторах, влияющих на
>   расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Приложении 3.

Comment: Даже независимо от того, что было в прошлом предложении?

Comment: Они поселились здесь, сея вражду. В то время как остальные жили в мире и согласии.

Comment: Из Приложения 3 к вышеприведённой ссылке:  _"Если придаточная часть предложения следует за главной – запятая ставится только перед союзом"_. В Вашем случае запятая **после** «в то время как» вряд ли целесообразна. Но если _"автор желает подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение"_, запятая возможна. Когда поселились? _**(Именно) в то время**, как остальные жили в мире и согласии._